PHP function to download file when called by a webhook
I have a webhook incoming to my server that runs a php script create an excel spreadsheet and stores it on a folder on my server.  What I want to do is trigger a download to the users PC of the file but everything I do either doesn't work at all or sends the file as code to the http response 200.
Ive got everything to create and store the excel file using PHPSpreadsheet and the file name is stored in
$fileUrl = 'https://example.co.uk/folder/' . $filename;

Ive tried all suggestions I can find on google but using header and readfile() all point back to the webhook sender not the browser downloads.
Is what Im trying to do even possible
Something like this would normally work but not when called from a webhook, it just sends code to the webhook sender as a response 200. On a side note, I cant change anything on the site that sends the webhook
 header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="' . $filename   
 . '"');
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
    header('Pragma: public');
    header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filepath));
    readfile($filepath);   



"I have a webhook incoming to my server" - and where in that do you think the user's browser was involved ...? "Is what Im trying to do even possible" - no, at least not directly. You would either need to make the client pull your server, until you get the info that the file has been created by now, or you'd need to set up some kind of push, that lets your server inform a specific client, that there is something to download now.

Any response you return in the script which processes the webhook call will go back to the code which sent the webhook call. There is no user involved. How would the system know what user to send the file to in that scenario, do you expect?

I was hoping to have some way of triggering a new tab or something as the browser is open when the webhook is sent

It is not clear how the 'webhook sender' and 'client browser' are connected. You need to 'inform' the 'client browser' somehow which file to download. As an idea you can return the file url by the webhook and pass it then to the client browser.

What if 100 users have browsers open connected to your site at that time? How would this system know which one to send it to? Where does the webhook call originate exactly? Maybe there's something about this scenario you haven't made clear, which would explain how you expect it could work in a practical sense. Maybe if the webhook call contains a user ID, and you have a websocket connection open and identifiable by the ID, php could send a message to it containing the file URL, and some JS in the page could then initiate the download. Not sure if that is what you were thinking of

OK thanks, you've helped with my understanding of why its not going to work. Unless I can get a way to manipulate the response code when it hits the webhook sender then I've got no chance. I guess the 200 response cant include an attachment and only code.

A http response can contain a body as well, which can be a file - the structure of a response is no different for different clients. There's still a status code, headers, and (optionally) some body data. But it depends whether the webhook sender is programmed to actually do anything with that response data. And you haven't made clear what the sender of the webhook is, or how that would relate to a specific user of your site

I solved this by adding an email field to the webhook and using PHPMailer to send the file once created

That seems like a pretty sensible solution.
